# Como passar uma classe como parâmetro em outra classe e retornar uma variável que está dentro de uma Thread

Tags: java, android, json, gson

Trabalho com Delphi e resolvi aprender a fazer aplicativos java, e me deparei com um problema.

Tenho esta classe

```
    public class Dados {
    public void getJson(final String url) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Object retorno = null;
                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet request       = new HttpGet();

                    request.setURI(new URI(url));

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
                    InputStream content   = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    Reader reader         = new InputStreamReader(content);

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    retorno   = gson.fromJson(reader, HashMap.class);

                    content.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

A classe a cima funciona, mas eu gostaria de fazer duas coisas a mais nela. Primeiro eu gostaria de passar uma classe (qualquer classe) como parâmetro e depois retornar o que esta na variável "retorno", como por exemplo:

```
 public class Dados {
    public Class<T> getJson(Class<T> classeTal, final String url) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Object retorno = null;
                try {
                    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet request       = new HttpGet();

                    request.setURI(new URI(url));

                    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(request);
                    InputStream content   = response.getEntity().getContent();
                    Reader reader         = new InputStreamReader(content);

                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    retorno   = gson.fromJson(reader, classeTal.class);

                    content.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }).start();
    return retorno;
    }
}
```

Alguém poderia me dizer como eu faria isso e se puder me dar um exemplo? Pois o exemplo que dei não funciona.

Comment: Isso pode ser feito mas pode utilizar a classe [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) que permite isso e algo mais.

Comment: Beleza @ramaral vou tentar aplicar a classe AsyncTask e ver se resolve meu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que você pode tentar com generics, por exemplo:

```
public class Dados<T> implements Runnable{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        T object = (T)new Object(); 
    }
}

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dados dados = new Dados<String>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Valeu, utilizei a sua dica juntando com o AsyncTask e deu certo consegui passar a classe como parâmetro.